# How to set all bash args, except the first two, to git alias

Tags: bash, git, alias

I want to create a git alias which will create a commit message with a template defined by me.

This is the template:

> "[$firstVariable] $secondVariable: $thirdVariable"

1. The first one is the **branch number**,
2. the second one is the **type of commit**,
3. and the last arguments are the **subject of the commit message**

Exemple:

> "[1000] feat: add new sales controller"

This is my bash function in `.gitconfig` file:

```
[alias]
    c = "!f() { branchNumber=${1}; type=${2}; shift; shift; subject=${*}; git commit -m '['"$branchNumber"'] '"$type"': '"$subject"' '; }; f"
```

I can get the first two variables, but in the third one there is a error in terminal.

If i execute this command, i get this:

Command: `$ git c 1000 feat add new sales controller`

Return:

> error: pathspec 'sales' did not match any file(s) known to git.
>
> error: pathspec 'controller ' did not match any file(s) known to git.

---

Observations:

- If i add a echo function at `$subject` the command return:

> new sales controller
>
> error: pathspec 'sales' did not match any file(s) known to git.
>
> error: pathspec 'controller ' did not match any file(s) known to git.

- If i just add one argument at `$subject` the alias is working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git "eats" one level of double quotes while parsing the `.gitconfig` line.  Hence, while you wrote:

```
"!f() { branchNumber=${1}; type=${2}; shift; shift; subject=${*}; git commit -m '['"$branchNumber"'] '"$type"': '"$subject"' '; }; f"
```

what the *shell* sees is:

```
!f() { branchNumber=${1}; type=${2}; shift; shift; subject=${*}; git commit -m '['$branchNumber'] '$type': '$subject' '; }; f
```

Note that the only quotes that remain are the single quotes, so that when `$subject` expands, it becomes separate words:

```
git c 1000 feat add new sales controller
```

becomes:

```
git
commit
-m
[1000] feat: add
new
sales
controller
```

(where I have drawn each "word" on a line by itself).  (There is also a blank after the word `controller`, since that was protected by single quotes.)  If you prefer, another way to draw this for StackOverflow posting purposes might be:

<kbd>`git`</kbd> <kbd>`commit`</kbd> <kbd>`-m`</kbd> <kbd>`[1000] feat: add`</kbd> <kbd>`new`</kbd> <kbd>`sales`</kbd> <kbd>`controller`</kbd>

That is, the command itself sees each of these as one separate "word": the commit log message is therefore `[1000] feat: add`; `new`, `sales`, and `controller` are treated as *pathspec* arguments.

One simple cure is to replace each double-quote that you wish to preserve with backslash-double-quote:

```
    c = "!f() { branchNumber=${1}; type=${2}; shift; shift; subject=${*}; git commit -m '['\"$branchNumber\"'] '\"$type\"': '\"$subject\"' '; }; f"
```

To make this more readable, observe that double quotes suffice for the entire `-m` argument (and that braces are not required in various places here):

```
    c = "!f() { branchNumber=$1; type=$2; shift 2; subject=$*; git commit -m \"[$branchNumber] ${type}: $subject\"; }; f"
```

Comment: Nice, it worked. Thx. But i want to clarify some points: 
1. Why just single quotes remain? 
2. Why each "word" is on a line by itself? 
3. Why braces are still required in `$type`?

Comment: 1. Take out the double quotes (Git does/did). What's left? 2. How would *you* draw this in a StackOverflow posting? Remember that the goal is to show which words are grouped together and which aren't. (There are other ways to draw this.) 3. They're technically not, but `${var:default}` is valid syntax, so I think it's less confusing to write `${var}:default` than to rely on knowing that `$var:default` is treated differently from `${var:default}`.

Comment: 2. I'll rephrase the question: I would like to know why all the words were grouped lonely, but `[1000] feat: add` was grouped together

Comment: What made some words are grouped togheter and which are not?

Comment: Whitespace. You quoted the explicit spaces, `' '`, but the *implied* spaces obtained by expanding `$var` *also* split words unless they're quoted. The only kind of quotes that you can use to quote them are double quotes—but Git takes away unescaped double quotes, so in the Git *alias* line, you need backslash-double-quote so that the *shell* gets the double-quote so that the *shell* doesn't split words at spaces.